# Python: libphonenumber - cannot get extract out obvious phone numbers

Tags: python, phone-number, libphonenumber

I am using Python version of Google's libphonenumbers, but when I tried this library on different texts, sometimes it will the python function will not return me anything while it is very obvious that there a phone number there and sometimes they do return the phone numbers. Please see below:

```
print(x2)
for match in pnum.PhoneNumberMatcher(x2, "US"):
print(match) #for the text above, it did not get the number
```

output:

```
I just read your profile and thought it was really great. I also thought you were cute and loved the fact that you go hiking with your brothers every summer. If you want to know anything more about me, just ask.  My num 555-121-5468.
```

With this text above, it does not return me any phone number.
But in other situation like the  following, this function gives me correct input:

```
x9 = "hay I hate to cut you short, its been fun chatting, but unfortuantely I gotta run. I am gald we became friends though. my number is (323) 2387890"

 for match in pnum.PhoneNumberMatcher(x9, "US"):
 print(match)
```

output:

```
 PhoneNumberMatch [132,145) (323) 2387890
```

I don't know what is the issue causing this problem, I am new to Python and this library and would sincerely appreciate insight.

Answer (score 1):

555-121-5468 looks like a  valid US phone number, but actually it isn't.

The `PhoneNumberMatcher` class [constructor](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/dev/python/phonenumbers/phonenumbermatcher.py#L469) accepts a `leniency` argument which defines how strictly the class matches candidate phone numbers ([code](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/dev/python/phonenumbers/phonenumbermatcher.py#L172)).  The possible values of this argument The default value of `leniency` is `1`, which will only match valid phone numbers.  Changing this to `0` will match possible phone numbers like 555-121-5468.

```
>>> for match in pnum.PhoneNumberMatcher(x2, 'US', leniency=0): 
print(match) 
...
PhoneNumberMatch [220,232) 555-121-5468
```

The 555 prefix is not a real prefix, but is used for fictional phone numbers in US TV and cinema.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number)):

> Telephone numbers with the prefix 555 are widely used for fictitious
>   telephone numbers in North American television shows, films, video
>   games, and other media in order to prevent practical jokers and
>   curious callers from bothering real people and organisations by
>   telephoning numbers they see in works of fiction; generally, in North
>   America, a number with 555 as a prefix will not connect to a real
>   person.